K3s ingress-nginx Is the DNS entry mandatory for configuring web applications
I've a very obvious question, Running K3s on a standalone server
where I want to run a web app pod configured with ingress-nginx, which should be accessible over IP within the subnet,
its not possible to get a DNS entry for the same..
Can this be done..?
Is the DNS mandatory..?
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: auth-app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target:  "/$2"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: 192.168.5.10
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: auth-app-service
            port:
              number: 3038

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-app-service
spec:
  ports:
  - name: auth-app
    port: 3038
    targetPort: 3038
    protocol: TCP
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: auth-app

